# Can I run Nginx outside a kuberntes cluster and have it discover ingresses?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a bare metal cluster. Right now I have traefik running on a machine, outside the cluster, playing reverse proxy. Basically it just points its backend to the cluster api-server. It will discover ingresses and works fine. But it doesn't support TCP :-(

Can I do the same with Nginx? Is there a way to run it outside the cluster and point its backend to the kubernetes api-server to discover ingresses?

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you want to run a Kubernetes ingress controller outside of a Kubernetes cluster? And if it is, what is the reason, because it is much more complex, then use regular one inside a cluster. Or you just want to use nginx as a reverse proxy to access to a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: If it doesn't support `TCP` .. what DOES it support?

Comment: It supports HTTP only. And yes I just want a reverse proxy to access the services within a cluster. But I think what I will try is to tie the Nginx-Ingress to a host in the cluster and expose it with hostPort. After which I will add another Nginx-Ingress hos to the cluster and have a floting VIP between them for some resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was run the ingress controller inside the cluster and tie it to a node which has the needed DNS entries pointing towards it with HostNetwork.